# Kindle Fire Freetime questions

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire, amazon-appstore

We have 2 kindle fires for each of our kids: 7 YO and 10 YO.  Like most kids all they want to do is watch YouTube.  I'd like to let them do that but with time limits and blocking inappropriate content (I know the blocking isn't perfect).  It seems like if I enable free time, there's no possibility for accessing YouTube.

Freetime also seems to have weird ideas of what websites are  appropriate for a 10 year old child.  I tried setting the age range in Free Time to the range 10-13+ and it's still recommending "Paw Patrol" and "Nick Jr. Preschooler."  This is for a 10 year old whose read the whole Harry Potter series and reads a 300 page young adult novel every week.

Other than me having to set a stopwatch or something is there an easy way to set time limits on a Fire without using Freetime.  The Windows parental controls, which I also use, seem to work a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, i do not believe there is any way, unless you are on a 3rd generation and up version of the kindle fire.

If you do have a kindle fire 3 and above, you could attempt to install google play store unofficially on the tablets, and find apps there that can do just what your asking, including youtube kids for them, and set an age limit on that app.

I personally do not recommend amazon tablets, as they dont come with a google play store pre-installed.

As to [this](https://getyeti.co/posts/how-to-install-the-google-playstore-in-your-amazon-fire-tablet) link, it states that you must:

1. "Go to settings > Security > click on enable unknown sources"
2. Download [Google Account Manager](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-account-manager/google-account-manager-5-1-1743759-release/google-account-manager-5-1-1743759-android-apk-download/) on your device
3. Download [Google Services Framework](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-services-framework/google-services-framework-5-1-1743759-release/google-services-framework-5-1-1743759-android-apk-download/) on your device
4. "If you have the 2017 Fire HD 8 download" [Google Play Store - Fire 8](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-11-5-09-release/google-play-services-11-5-09-230-164803921-android-apk-download/) otherwise [Google play store - other](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/google-play-store-7-0-25-h-all-0-release/google-play-store-7-0-25-h-0-android-apk-download/)
5. Install apps from .apk in order (Google account manager, Google Services Framework, Google Play Store)

The above method is for a tablet that has not been rooted, if you dont know what rooting is, it probably is not rooted.

I hope this helped

Comment: Looks like you confirmed what I was afraid of.  I'd read about rooting tablets and installing stuff from outside the Amazon store, but I'm not keen on installing random, free, closed source appliations on my tablets.

Comment: I'm going to try checking out these two apps: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01N1V79A7/?coliid=I2BFGLD4IXEXZ1&colid=2MSFRGER2X313&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it and https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00R1CR5RG/?coliid=I2LSFAT4SZBG50&colid=2MSFRGER2X313&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it.  I'm also going to see if I can do something in the settings on my wireless router.

Comment: Im not sure your router can be much help outside of blocking sites entirely, some routers allow for ad-blocking across the router, but very few. If you find a better answer, please post it here, otherwise please mark mine as the correct answer for the post.

Comment: I don't think I can do very sophisticated blocking from a router, but I understand some will allow you to do time limits on a per mac address basis.

Comment: There is a possibility of open source apps, that offer blocking on android devices, although you are going to still need them outside of the amazon app, and please post your own fix here, if you do find anything inside, or outside of the amazon store, so others with the same problem may benefit. Or if my answer is the way you end up needing to go, please mark it as the answer.